# Utility to detect defect C/C++ compiled/object file

Tags: compiling, c++, c

Is there a Linux utility to detect a defect C/C++ compiled/object file interrupted amidst its compilation progress ?
How its simplest usage ?

Comment: SE *Unix & Linux* provides Linux support; you've currently provided nothing on-topic for this site; please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: please post the exact error message

Comment: I'm not quite sure what kind of interrupted compilation you are dealing with, but a simply truncated ELF object file would likely be detectable by the `readelf` program e.g. `readelf --lint somefile.o >/dev/null` would emit an error like `Reading nnnn bytes extends past end of file for section headers`

Comment: I would expect a failed compile to not produce any file at all; i.e. clean the build tree before attempting to compile. No file after attempt => failed to produce one.

Comment: In my 35+ years of C/C++ programming I have NEVER come across an object file that was corrupted during compilation. That is just a total non-issue. And even if that happened, the linker would complain.